# VB reading from an access database

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

I have the following code and when I run it and the end of the line of code I get an error which states

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in
>   query expression

but I'm not to sure what it means, I am using vb (in visual studio) and an access database. The error appears on the line where I declare the `dr` variable (which I have used for my data reader).
Any help on this would be much appreciated many thanks,

```
Private Function CarFinder(b As String, m As String, s As String, d As Integer, e As String)
    myConnection.ConnectionString = My.Forms.Main.connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim match As String
    match = "SELECT * FROM CarFigures WHERE CBrand = '" & cbBrand.Text & "' CModel = '" &
        cbModel.Text & "' and CSpec = '" & cbSpec.Text & "'"


Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(match, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", m)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", d)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", e)
        Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.Read Then
            CO2e = dr("CCO2")
            Ins = dr("InsuranceBand")
            mpg = dr("CMPG")
            time = dr("C060Time")
            ncap = dr("CarNCAP")
            bik = dr("Bik Rating")

        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your SQL Query String is wrong.  Your missing an `AND` betwen "cbBrand.Text" and "CModel =".  It should be like the following...

```
match = "SELECT * FROM CarFigures WHERE CBrand = '" & cbBrand.Text & "' and  CModel = '" & cbModel.Text & "' and CSpec = '" & cbSpec.Text & "'"
```

Comment: ahh yes thank you, I missed it when I was rereading the code thank you

Comment: another question what does this error mean  "System.IndexOutOfRangeException"